# how to use custom templates for same classes in field plugin, grails

Tags: templates, grails, plugins, field

For example I have 2 class:

```
Person {
  String name
  String descriptionOfPerson
}

Company {
  String name
  String descriptionOfCompany
}
```

Normally, fields plugin will use the same template `/_fields/string/_field.gsp` for all of them.

But I want to use `/_fields/string/_field.gsp` template for `String name` and `/_fields/ckeditor/_field.gsp` (to render ckeditor) for `descriptionOfPerson` and `descriptionOfCompany`

Is it possible to do like that? And how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the plugin and it's [documentation](http://freeside.co/grails-fields/guide/customizingFieldRendering.html) this **is not possible** without modifications on your side.

The default order in which the plugin searches for the templates is:

1. **grails-app/views/controllerName/actionName/propertyName/**
2. **grails-app/views/controllerName/actionName/propertyType/**
3. *grails-app/views/controllerName/actionName/ (not applicable here)*
4. **grails-app/views/controllerName/propertyName/**
5. *grails-app/views/controllerName/propertyType/ (not applicable here)*
6. *grails-app/views/controllerName/ (not applicable here)*
7. **grails-app/views/_fields/class/propertyName/**
8. **grails-app/views/_fields/superclass/propertyName/**
9. *grails-app/views/_fields/associationType/ (not applicable here)*
10. grails-app/views/_fields/propertyType/
11. *grails-app/views/_fields/propertySuperclass/ (not applicable here)*
12. grails-app/views/_fields/default/

Neither is there a possibility to pass a custom template, nor to distinguish between between the property name when the template is found via the property's class.

However, there are some possibilities to realize your case.

#### A) Template condition

You could include a condition into the `/_fields/string/_field.gsp` template and make use of the provided *template parameters*, such as:

```
<g:if test="${property == 'descriptionOfPerson' || property == 'descriptionOfCompany' }">
    <!-- render your ckeditor here or include another template via g:render -->
</g:if>
<g:else>
    <!-- render your normal input here or include another template via g:render -->
</g:else>
```

#### B) Template for each controller property

for instance:
`grails-app/views/_fields/person/description/` and
`grails-app/views/_fields/company/description/`.
Both templates could include another template via `g:render`, being place at `grails-app/views/_fields/ckeditor/`

Applying this to your example, you could place the template in any of the **bold** paths and it would be preferred to the `/_fields/string/_field.gsp` template.

Personally I would stick with B), which allows a more fine-grained control and is easier to understand for others that are not familiar with your code. I would also rename both of your fields to `description`. As always, this decision depends on your complete application and its overall complexity.

Comment: For my current project, I will stick with A) (with a addition parameter to decide which template should I render) because there are like ~80 descriptions in different domains and I don't want to create tons of folder

Comment: Another idea is that it is possible to create a customType to mapping  a java class to a column in database (For example I can mapping a StringMediumText class to a column with a constraint like sqlType " 'mediumText') (using hibernate...). And then write a template in '_fields/stringMediumText/_field.gsp'. But it's really complex.

Answer (score 0):

The default rendering mechanism of the fields plugin (without using the override template stuff) uses the [widget constraint of grails](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/widget.html) to render a textarea instead of a `<input type="text" />` (as you see [in the source of the fields plugin](https://github.com/gpc/grails-fields/blob/master/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/formfields/FormFieldsTagLib.groovy#L373)).

With an unobtrusive javascript library (ckeditor seems to have these capabilities as described in their [dev guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Integration)), that replaces a `<textarea>` with something more exciting, the only thing you have to do is the following:

```
Person {
  String name
  String descriptionOfPerson

  static constraints = {
    descriptionOfPerson widget: 'textarea'
  }

}

Company {
  String name
  String descriptionOfCompany

  static constraints = {
    descriptionOfCompany widget: 'textarea'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's only for the case we play around with textarea. In my project there are other case like: a String with constraints inList and need to be rendered as select... So, I decide to use extra parameters to render different template inside `/_fields/string/_field.gsp`. It could be the simple solution (only for my current project)

Comment: in this case, i would go exactly the same way, but instead override `/_fields/string/_input.gsp`. The drawback of this solution is, that you loose the default rendering stuff of the fields plugin (like html5 client validation constraints and so on...). Another solution could be a [pull request](https://github.com/gpc/grails-fields/pull/116) that is currently pending, in which you can create some kind of 'components' and use this for distinction. But in order to use this, you will have to use the master branch directly, because realeses of the fields plugin are quite rare...

Answer (score 0):

At least now (2 years after initial post) I found 2 working solutions for me:

(1) specify for **every** field I want to have wysiwyg editor functionality a sub-folder in views (like grails-app/views/myDomainObject/myWysiwygField/_wrapper.gsp) with the following content:

```
<div class="fieldcontain${required ? ' required' : ''}">
<label for="${property}">${label}<g:if test="${required}"> <span class="required-indicator">*</span></g:if></label>
<ckeditor:config var="toolbar_Mytoolbar">
[
    [ 'Undo', 'Redo', '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', '-', 'NumberedList', 'BulletedList']
]
</ckeditor:config>
<ckeditor:editor name="${property}" width="40%" toolbar="Mytoolbar">${value}</ckeditor:editor> <!-- toolbar="Basic" -->
</div>
```

(2) declare the wysiwyg fields as textarea

```
static constraints = {
    myWysiwygField widget: "textarea"
}
```

and define (once) grails-app/views/_fields/textarea/_wrapper.gsp with the same content than above.

So the first one is more fine-granular while the second one is more appealing for simpler problems.